# How old are the characters in the Cars movies?

Tags: character, cars

In one scene of the first movie, Sally recalls as far back as 40 years earlier, when things were different. Although we don't see her in the flashback all other Radiator Springs folks are there and don't seem to be that young already.

> Forty years ago, that Interstate down there didn't exist. Back then, cars came across the country a whole different way. Well, the road didn't cut through the land like that Interstate. It moved with the land, it rose, it fell, it curved. Cars didn't drive on it to make great time. They drove on it to have a great time.
>
> — Sally Carrera, *Cars* (2006)

So how old are they actually?

Comment: As old as the models they are based on one supposes.

Comment: @Paulie_D assume it's set in the present, and not the past nor some post-BnL dystopia.

Comment: @OrangeDog I have no idea what that means. We don't know ehen Car is set (we can only approximate) but since most of the characters are based on actual models that's the only indication we have.

Comment: That's my point: given we don't know when it's set, the age of the actual models is of no use.

Comment: The only thing we can say from in-universe is that their ages are never told

Comment: "In one scene of the first movie, Sally recalls as far back as 40 years earlier, when things were different." I can describe something that took place 200 years ago, that doesn't make me that old; and I'm not "recalling" it.

Comment: @sirjonsnow as I said in the question, all of the other folks are there in the "memory"

Comment: @OrangeDog: Lightning Mcqueen is the pinnacle of engineering, as he is actively in use for races and highly popular. This gives us a good estimate. Lightning seems mostly based on a Corvette, and the general design aesthetic feels very ['95 Corvette](https://assets.hemmings.com/uimage/19827605-770-0@2X.jpg) ([comparison](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/9f/83/29/9f83299b49a7f27ff7eb7df5add5fb8f.jpg)). It's the rounded corners that make me suspect it focuses heavily on the 90's. The 00's are more aerodynamic, and the 80's were more angular. **TL;DR It takes place in the 90's**

Comment: @OrangeDog - At the end of the licenced video-game *Cars: The Video Game* we see the Piston Cup that Lightning would have won, had he won the final race. It's dated 2006; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFL653yBru8

Answer (score 1):

According to the licenced '[Meet the Cars](https://pixarcars.fandom.com/wiki/Meet_the_Cars)' factbook, Lightning McQueen is a...

> "*2006 Custom-Built Piston Cup Racer*".

...and given that the current [2006 Piston Cup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOYvn.png) is his rookie year, this makes him **just under 1 year of age** at the time of the first film.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[Meet the Cars](https://pixarcars.fandom.com/wiki/Meet_the_Cars)</sup></sub>

Sally, by comparison, is a ...

> *"2002 Porche Carrera"*

... making her approximately **4** years of age at the start of the first film.

> [image]

Since the installation of the highway took place "*40 years ago*", her  recollection of the town before the Interstate can only be based on *other people's descriptions* of what happened, rather than any first-hand knowledge.

---

Purely for the record, the other characters in Radiator Springs are described thusly;

> - Fillmore  - 1960
> - Ramone  - 1959
> - Luigi - 1959
> - Flo  - 1956
> - Red  - "1950s"
> - Doc Hudson - 1951
> - Sheriff - 1949
> - Sarge  - 1942
> - Lizzie  - 1923